# A rectangular matrix of full rank can be multiplied by infinitely many matrices to form the identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

> Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix with $m < n$ and $\operatorname{rank}(A) = m$. Prove that there exist infinitely many matrices $B$ such that $AB = I$.

Stumped. How do I begin to prove this?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the $j$'th column of $B$ must be a vector $\bf x$ such that $A{\bf x} = \ldots$.  What do you know about solving equations $A {\bf x} = \bf b$ when $A$ is $m \times n$ with rank $m$ and $m < n$?

Comment: the solutions are linearly independent?

Comment: No, that's not it...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**-For a matrix $A$ of order $m×n$, $m<n$ ; the system **$Ax_j$=$b$** has infinitely many solutions. Now, consider $x_j$ as $j^th$ column of matrix $B$.